# Keepalived upstream connection to Unicorn via socket

Tags: nginx, unicorn

Nginx 1.1.4+ can serve upstream connection with HTTP1.1 **keepalive** directive, see the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#keepalive) (it's not the same as keepalived clients' connections). So the Unicorn configuration can look like as below:

```
upstream unicorn {
  server             unix:/tmp/unicorn.todo.sock fail_timeout=0;
  keepalive          4;
}

server {
  try_files          $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  keepalive_timeout  70;

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_pass         http://unicorn;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
  }
}
```

These headers are required for HTTP connection: **proxy_http_version** and **proxy_set_header**.

So the question is the configuration valid or socket-connection is permanent by itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. There's no difference between UNIX-socket and TCP/IP-socket in terms of HTTP Keepalive.

Comment: thanks a lot! It would be also great to get your professional feedback about the configuration https://gist.github.com/3052776

Comment: VBart: [Unicorn docs says](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html) "Since Unicorn is only designed for applications that send the response body quickly without keepalive, sockets will always be flushed on close to prevent delays." Does it mean the nginx upstream connection overheaded?

Comment: It seems. http://unicorn.bogomips.org/DESIGN.html says *Like Mongrel, neither keepalive nor pipelining are supported.* Then the "keepalive" option for unicorn is useless, and introduces a small processing overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Unicorn doesn't support persistent (keep-alive) connection by design. So, you shouldn't try to use persistent (keep-alive) connection to unicorn backend.